# iOS / Objective-C: UIView delegates not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, delegates

i´ve got a uiview in a scrollview which is in a viewcontroller and it seems that the delegates are not called because i added them to the uiview.

Is it possible to solve this problem? (I want to keep the delegates in the uiview because it seems to be cleaner code)

Maik

EDIT:

in .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface RHCHuntingReportViewPageTwo : UIView <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

in .m file:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *pin=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin.png"];
    pin.draggable = NO;
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return pin;
}
```

I added the delegate and outlet correctly in storyboard.

edit 2:

in .m file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        RHCAnnotation *annotation = [[RHCAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = @"title";
        annotation.subtitle = @"subtitle";
        annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_tipp.png"];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(57.242465, 2.533579);
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 250, 250);
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You should provide some sample code

Comment: Did you set your delegate property correctly?

Comment: What delegates are we talking about?

Comment: viewForAnnotation won't get called unless you've done addAnnotation somewhere.  And in this case, it's the mapView delegate you're talking about (mapView.delegate = self;)

Comment: sorry, forgot some code... added it.. i set the delegate in storyboard and i can see it there in the outlets view

Comment: try adding the annotation in viewDidLoad, not initWithCoder.  Also, to be certain you can do mapView.delegate = self; in initWithCoder.

Comment: There is no viewDidLoad method in UIView, it´s only in UIViewController. To set the delegate in code doesn´t solve the problem...

Comment: Do you at least see a red pin where the annotation image should be?  Is there a reason you're using initWithCoder?  Try using awakeFromNib instead (eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805330/initialization-of-controls-in-custom-uiview).

Comment: Yes, awakeFromNib works fine! Thank you!